# 'not defined' error in my code kindly assist

Tags: python

this is my second week coding and I keep getting an error on my code, any assistance will greatly be appreciated.

```
name1="brian"
height_m1=1.74
weight_kg1=83
name2="adams"
height_m2=1.76
weight_kg2=68
name3="ricky"
height_m3=1.7
weight_kg3=60
def bmi_calculator(name, height_m, weight_kg):
    bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
    print("bmi: ")
    print(bmi)
    if bmi < 25:
        returnname + "is not overweight"
    else:
        returnname + "is overweight"
result1=bmi_calculator(name1, height_m1, weight_kg1)
result2=bmi_calculator(name2, height_m2, weight_kg2)
result3=bmi_calculator(name3, height_m3, weight_kg3)
print(result1)
print(result2)
print(result3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<input>", line 18, in <module>
    File "<input>", line 17, in bmi_calculator
NameError: name 'returnname' is not defined
```

Comment: put a space between `return` and `name`, `returnname` is a variable that hasn't been defined

Comment: Give space between return and name

Answer (score 1):

Give space between return and name it should be like this.

```
return name+”your string”
```